# CPP insert into sorted linkedlist getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm implementing a method in sorted linked list.

```
void insertInOrder(ListType & list, Node *itemP);
```

And ListType is defined as below.

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;

  Node(int item);
  Node(int item, Node *n);

};

typedef Node * ListType;
```

Here is how i implement the method.

```
void insertInOrder(ListType & list, Node *itemP) {
    if (list == NULL || itemP->data <= list->data) {
        itemP->next = list;
        list = itemP;
        return;
    }

    ListType p1 = list;
    ListType p2 = p1->next;

    while (p2 != NULL) {
        if (p2->data > itemP->data) {
            itemP->next = p2;   
            p1->next = itemP;
            return;
        }
        p1 = p2; 
        p2 = p2->next;
    }
    p1->next = itemP;
}
```

However, I am keep getting segmentation fault when adding the third item. Adding first 2 is ok, for example, (10 -> 12). If I want to add more, then getting the error no matter which number i put. I couldn't find the problem so i am seeking help here.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question "how do you debug a segmentation fault"? If so, you need to tell us what platform you are using, what debugger you prefer, and so on.

Comment: You can't use `list` as variable name.

Comment: `itemP->next = list;` Here, you are casting reference to pointer!